# aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService can't set capacity provider strategies of fargate service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to incorporate Fargate and fagate spot capacity providers into my ECS cluster and automate them as code. But the [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns/ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html) by itself creates an object of [FargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateService.html?highlight=fargate#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.FargateService). Using the [service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns/ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.service) method exposed I got a copy of the created object. Since there were no getters or setters for the capacity_provider_strategies of the fagateService I could not set the [capacity_provider_strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateService.html?highlight=fargate#:%7E:text=capacity_provider_strategies) attribute of that object. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You can try the Escape Hatches if you don't find a nice solution within Level 2 constructs. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html